# Broken Packages: php-apc: Depends: phpapi-20090626+lfs

Tags: server, php, lighttpd

I need to install php-apc on Ubuntu 10.04 and Ubuntu 9.04

First of all, can I just install this package to make it work with php 5.2 + lighttpd on these Ubuntu versions ?

I've tried to install it on Ubuntu 10.04 and I get the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install php-apc

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  php-apc: Depends: phpapi-20090626+lfs
E: Broken packages
```

thanks

Comment: I realize it has been awhile since activity on this but did you ever get this resolved. I am dealing with the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: [fluteflute](http://askubuntu.com/users/866/fluteflute)'s [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/19701/22949) has been accepted, so you might try that and see if it works. If it doesn't, you should post a new question detailing your problem and also including a link to this question. (Your post here will probably be [deleted soon](http://askubuntu.com/faq#deletion), since it is posted as an answer but is not an attempt to answer the question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

php-apc cannot be installed because it depends on the virtual package [phpapi-20090626+lfs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/phpapi-20090626+lfs). For the system to consider this virtual package 'installed', then you need to have installed either Apache or PHP.

Seeing as you don't need Apache I would suggest you install the `php5-cgi` package. (This will give you PHP 5.3 in 10.04.)

Comment: I actually don't want to upgrade to php 5.3, because it doesn't support Drupal 6 yet. Can I make it with php 5.2 ?

Comment: @Patrick according to the [drupal website](http://drupal.org/requirements) you can use PHP 5.3 with the latest Drupal 6 releases

Comment: I know but it is an optimistic statement. I work with it and some modules are not properly working. Trust me.